C++ Why do std::vector<> and std::list<> not share a common base class/interface?
Since im mainly working on C#. After quite some time a had to work on a C++ project and was wondering why C++ isn't relying on inheritance or interfaces for related methods such as std::vector<>::begin(T, Allocator) and std::list<T, Allocator>::begin()? In C# this is commonly used for classes with a similar behaviour such as the ICollection<T> interface on List<T> and ReadOnlyCollection<T>.

In general, applying one programming language's idea of something directly to other isn't recommended.

This also seems like implementation detail perhaps.

C++ doesn't use "interfaces" nearly as often as C# for various reasons, so it makes no sense to have them. Inheritance hierarchies are horrible anyways, so I'm not sure what you're looking for.

In C++ templates are using duck typing, so common interface in pointless.

I believe that one reason is performance (avoiding virtual/dynamic dispatch).

In C# this is commonly used for classes with a similar behaviour -- As mentioned there is no point in C++ to implement things this way when templates exist.  As long as the type has the same characteristics, the types can have nothing to do with each other, but still share common code.  If there is a template function on type T, and in the function it calls T::begin();, it doesn't matter what T is, whether it is a base class of some type, or something you made up out of thin air without any "interface" jazz going on.  As long as it has a begin() function, that's all that matters.

Because C++ has better support for generic programming. The hierarchy in C# (and Java) is a workaround for lacking such support.

On a side note, we used to have to do the hierarchy thing in C++ before the addition of templates.

@molbdnilo when was that? I thought templates were implemented by (versions of) cfront

@Caleth • C++ 3.0 (1991) added class templates and function templates.  The next version was ISO C++98, which added a lot of things.  Perforce C++ history.

C++ actually supports interfaces in multiple ways

by virtual functions. This is classical style nominal subtyping and that corresponds to the C# approach you quote
C++ does support interfaces in the classical sense where an interface is class-like with abstract functions. In c++ this would be pure virtual functions. This equivalent to what other languages offer. However this comes with a performance penalty as calling virtual functions has a performance hit as compared to regular functions (which moreover can also be inlined).
Besides the performance penalty, the disadvantage is that it is not possible to add interfaces to existing types. (This applies to all languages with this feature not just C++)

by concepts1. This is the more modern interface approach based on structural subtyping.
std::vector or std::list do not have a virtual function based interface because of performance reasons. Nevertheless they follow naming and conceptual conventions. Both have iterators (of different class though, but iterators) and have common function such as begin end insert, push_back and so on. There is even std::begin which can operate on all containers.
Structural subtyping for interfaces is also used in the Go language. It offers much more flexibility and extensibility. For instance one can add interfaces to existing types without having to change to existing type.
With C++20 concepts1 it is now also possible to explicitly specify the requirements on the types (i.e. what methods they must support, or more generally which expressions that operate on them must be valid). This defines interfaces (or concepts how they are called in C++). But this is decided not by the type implementer, but rather by the usage of the type.


So bottom line: They do not share a common (virtual) base class due to performance reasons. But they do share a common interface in the sense of structural subtyping (via C++ concepts).
Notes

On a technical level the C++11 std::enable_if provides the same functionality. C++20 concepts are much cleaner, though and more "interface" like in the modern sense.

Addendum: An example which demonstrates that inheritance (where nominal subtyping is closely related to) is really limiting and not adequate is numbers. Assume we have 'complex', 'float', 'int'. According to normal rules 'complex' should be the base class and all others inherit from it. For a compiled language this would result int a big performance hit already.
When one has fixed bit width, it becomes even more complicated. int32 would be a subtype to int64, and to float64, but not to float32 and so on. Together with arbitrary length integers this becomes completely messy.
A structural type system is then the much better approach, where compatibility rules are decided on properties of the types rather than inheritance. Same applies to interfaces.

To clarify, C++20 concepts don't offer any new possibilities here, they are just a cleaner way to express type requirements compared to the old std::enable_if.

"This applies to all languages with this feature not just C++" actually, no it doesn't. Go in particular doesn't require you to declare that your type implements some interface. And you can in fact hack something very similar in C++ the same way you implement std:: function.

@PasserBy But go does not fit into category 1, it is category 2.. Not sure what you mean actually ....

@HolyBlackCat True, I added a footnote. Thanks

@PasserBy I mean in category 1 languages you always have virtual functions under the hood. In category 2 languages one could have virtual functions (such as go), but it could also be compile time (as in C++). No?

No, I mean you get the virtual function behaviour without explicitly declaring it, which is what you get with std::function.

For me your answer feels a bit misleading. Especially part2 feels not as a interface definition at all. It simply implements a kind of duck typing, means something behaves like something, so it is something. But this has nothing to do with SFINAE or concepts. Concepts or SFINAE can lift the level of error detection but did not change anything.

@Klaus  Python for instance calls part2 "Protocols" which for me 100% an interface definition (in the structural subtyping sense, of course). If I look at the C++ predefined requirements I see EqualityComparable, Swappable, CopyConstructible which no more or less means that the type implements the EqualityComparable, Swappable, CopyConstructible "interface". Just because C++ calls it requirement it is in my understanding clearly just another name for interface.
